# How to count macs and parameters during forwarding in models or layers by pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, complexity-theory

```py
class model(nn.Module)
    def __init__()
        self.l1 = nn.linear(10,10)
        self.l2 = nn.linear(10,10)
    def forward(x)
        y1 = self.l1(x)
        y2 = self.l2(x)
        y3 = y1 + y2
        return y2 + y2 + y3*y1
```

In this example, I could use forward_hook functions to trace two linear layers and their parameters.fn is hook function.

```
m.register_forward_hook(fn)
```

However, `y3` is not counted as a parameter and the macs of `y2 + y2 + y3*y1` is not counted in macs, too.
How can I solve this?

"macs" is a way of measuring layers' complexity. For example, y1 *(y2 + y3) is one macs, if y1, y2, y3 are floats.

Comment: What is a "mac"?

Comment: macs is similiar to flops. It is used to measure layers complexity. It means a multiplication and a addition of floats. For example (y1+y2)*y3 is one macs, since y1, y2, y3 are floats.

Comment: Have you checked this repo? https://github.com/Lyken17/pytorch-OpCounter

Comment: Actually I have checked this repo, and sadly it does not provide this.

Comment: @MaxwellAlbert what's missing in this repo that you require exactly?

Comment: As in the example, this repo only calculate macs and params in module but not all in forward. Please look at the example.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like [PyTorch-OpCounter](https://github.com/Lyken17/pytorch-OpCounter) is a perfect fit for your use case:

1. Define your `nn.Module` class:

   ```py
   class NN(nn.Module):
       def __init__(self):
           super().__init__()
           self.l1 = nn.Linear(10, 10)
           self.l2 = nn.Linear(10, 10)

       def forward(self, x):
           y1 = self.l1(x)
           y2 = self.l2(x)
           y3 = y1 + y2
           return y2 + y2 + y3*y1
   ```
2. Initialize your model and input:

   ```py
   model = NN()
   x = torch.empty(16, 10)
   ```
3. Import [`thop`](https://pypi.org/project/thop/) and call the profiler:

   ```py
   from thop import profile
   macs, params = profile(model, inputs=(x,))
   ```

There you have your results:

```
>>> macs, params
(3200.0, 220.0)
```

Comment: Well, actually I have pull some requests to this repo. It is sure that this repo only count params and macs in models. However, there are computation out of the model but in forwarding. I don't agree with this, sorry.

Comment: Also, this repo use hook and dfs to count params and macs, which limits its power to trace computation.

Comment: *there are computation out of the model but in forwarding* what do you mean by that?

Comment: Let's see the example I provided. opcounter will calculate linear1 and linear2 since it uses foward_hook. However, y2 + y2 + y3*y1 and y3 itself is not calculated.